# How to make service selling website on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web, service

I want to make a website in wordpress where I can sell my service packages. For exmaple social media managements.

I want to add option for social link, duration and calculate the price according all information.

Can anyone help me out with this.

I am trying some theme. but this does not work.

Comment: (Try making good use of a spelling checker.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gravity form and woocommerce and add virtual products.

Comment: Can I show the order status with the gravity form for my customer? If there are any tutorials or guidelines. Please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: yes you can show with wocommerce custom code $order = new WC_Order($order_id);